# How do you Alphabetically order a String array using a Char array?

Tags: java, arrays

Okay so here's what I have so far:

```
Scanner key = new Scanner (System.in);
String[] main = new String[10];

for(int k = 0; k< main.length; k++)
{
   System.out.println("Enter a lower case letter! ");
   main[k] = key.nextLine();
}
for(int z = 1; z < 11; z++)
{
    char[] array = main[z-1].toCharArray();
    System.out.println(array);
}        
for(char c : array)
{
   System.out.println(c);
}
```

However, I have not found a way to print it, I think the **char array** is set up correctly, but I have little knowledge of how char arrays work. Also, it is worth noting that I cannot use `Arrays.sort`; however, I can use `String.compareTo`. I am trying to get a string array like a,j,d,f,h,y,d,a,d,g to print it out in alphabetical order without using `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: The code you posted can't compile/ You're trying to access `array` from the outside of the block where it's defined. What are you trying to achieve? Use an example. Let's say you have an array containing "hello", "world" and 8 other strings. Then what?

Comment: is your question to sort the array, or print it? you can find how to print an array here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array.

Comment: If you want to sort the array without using a built in, I would recommend some of the simpler sorting algorithms. check out bubble sort for example. it is not an efficient algorithm,  but it is a straight forward one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use java.util.Arrays sort() method.

```
//public static void sort(char[] a)

char[] a = {'c','a','b'};
Arrays.sort(a);
```

You can convert String to char array and sort the char array and create a new String out of it.

If you want to sort array of Strings(or in general for any Objects which implement Comparable interface), use

```
public static void sort(Object[] a)
```

Comment: I cannot use any imported utilities, sorry

Comment: but it belongs to java.utils package not external dependency

Comment: @premkumar You imported `Scanner`.

Comment: @bradimus how? only java.util.Arrays will be imported .

Comment: Sorry, comment was meant for @TheFaceHugger

Comment: It is for my AP computer science class I cannot use array.sort